# Passing an invalid user id, code should display message but the dbms_output is blank

Tags: if-statement, plsql, cursor

This procedure should list all project IDs mapped to the active user, and on passing an invalid user id it should print "User is not valid". However, no message is getting displayed.

```
PROCEDURE get_pid_info (p_return_status_o      OUT VARCHAR2,
                        p_error_message_o      OUT VARCHAR2,
                        p_user_id           IN     VARCHAR2)
IS
  CURSOR c_pid
  IS
       SELECT DISTINCT xpppa.project_id,
                       papf.person_type_id,
                       xpppp.end_date_active,
                       papf.person_id,
                       COUNT (DISTINCT xpppa.project_id) pid_count
         FROM xxcas_prj_pa_projects_all xpppa,
              xxcas_prj_pa_project_players xpppp,
              per_all_people_f papf
        WHERE     xpppa.project_id = xpppp.project_id
              AND xpppp.person_id = papf.person_id
              AND papf.person_id = 61--p_user_id
              AND xpppp.project_role_type = 'PROJECT MANAGER'
              AND papf.person_type_id = 6
              and sysdate between xpppa.start_date and nvl(xpppa.completion_date,sysdate+1)
              and sysdate between xpppp.start_date_active and nvl(xpppp.end_date_active,sysdate+1)
              AND EXISTS
                     (SELECT 1
                        FROM pa_lookups
                       WHERE     lookup_type = 'XXCAS_PRJ_USER_DETAILS'
                             AND description=papf.email_address
                             AND enabled_flag = 'Y'
                             AND SYSDATE BETWEEN start_date_active
                                             AND NVL (end_date_active,
                                                      SYSDATE + 1))
     GROUP BY xpppa.project_id,
              papf.person_type_id,
              xpppp.end_date_active,
              papf.person_id;
BEGIN
  FOR l_rec IN c_pid
  LOOP
     IF l_rec.project_id IS NOT NULL
     THEN
        dbms_output.put_line (
              'The Projects mapped to the active user ID are : '
           || l_rec.project_id);
     ELSIF l_rec.end_date_active < SYSDATE
     THEN
        dbms_output.put_line (
           'The user has been end dated in the system on : ' || l_rec.end_date_active);
     ELSIF l_rec.pid_count = 0
     THEN
        dbms_output.put_line (
           'There are no projects mapped to the user having PM role');
     ELSE 
        dbms_output.put_line ('Please check the user ID passed');
     END IF;

     IF SQL%NOTFOUND 
     THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('Entered user id is not valid');
     end if;

  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('Please provide valid user ID');
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('Error in get_pid' || SQLERRM);
END get_pid_info;
```

Anonymous Block:

```
declare
    status varchar2(30);
    msg varchar2(30);
begin
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE('20000000'); 
    XXCAS_PRJ_PROJECT_DTLS.GET_PID_INFO(status,msg,61);
end;
```

Comment: It needs to check whether the cursor loop found any rows to process. `sql%notfound` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if there are no rows to process then the loop is not entered and so any check inside it will not be executed.

Secondly, the [`SQL%` cursor attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sql_cursor.htm) apply to implicit cursors, not named ones like `c_pid` in your procedure. It would be simplest to declare a Boolean variable, initialise it to `FALSE` and set it to `TRUE` in the loop; then you can check its value after the loop. (Or if you want the actual number of rows, use `c_pid%rowcount` and initialise it to 0.)

I'm assuming this is a simplified version of your actual procedure, as `dbms_output` is not generally useful in production code unless the caller is set up to capture it.